# Figuring out the distribution of sample variance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If I have a random sample $X_1,...,X_m$ with normal observations where mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ then how can I show that $s_x^2=\sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_i-\bar{x})^2$~$\frac{\sigma^2}{m-1}\chi_{m-1}^2$ ?

I know that $s_x^2=\dfrac{s_x^2(m-1)}{\sigma^2}*\dfrac{\sigma^2}{m-1}$ and I know that $\dfrac{s_x^2(m-1)}{\sigma^2}$~$\chi_{m-1}^2$. But from here how do I get to $s_x^2=\sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_i-\bar{x})^2$~$\frac{\sigma^2}{m-1}\chi_{m-1}^2$ ? I just don't see it.  Thanks

Comment: $s_x^2=\sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_i-\bar{x})$ is a random variable whose _mean_ is $0$, and thus $x_x^2$ can take on both positive and negative values. This raises issues as to whether $s_x^2$ is _appropriate_ notation since $s_x$ can be imaginary.

Comment: I forgot to add the exponent in there sorry.

Comment: If $\frac ab Y \sim G$, then $Y \sim \frac ba G$. Apply this with $Y = s_x^2, a = m-1, b = \sigma^2, G = \chi_{m-1}^2$ to what you say you _know_.

Comment: I'm going to try to prove this result. It's not in my text book and I have never seen this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it suffices to prove that $A\sim B\implies tA\sim tB$ for $t>0$.

Recall that $A\sim B$ means that $\mathbb P(A\leq x)=\mathbb P(B\leq x)$ for all $x$. Now replace $x$ with $x/t$ to obtain:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(tA\leq x)&=\mathbb P(A\leq \frac{x}{t})\\
&=\mathbb P(B\leq \frac{x}{t})\\
&=\mathbb P(tB\leq x).
\end{align*}
$$
Hence $tA\sim tB$.

Comment: Yeah I haven't done very many proofs involving finding distributions. Ill try to look this up in my book. The tilda means that its distribution of the random variable right? And why would $B$ be a random variable?

Comment: Careful.... Does this work for $t < 0$?

Comment: For $t<0$, the same argument works with the middle two inequalities flipped (and the same exact conclusion).

Comment: The $\sim$ means that $A,B$ are random variables with the same distribution. It is equivalent to saying $\mathbb P(A\leq x)=\mathbb P(B\leq x)$.